# Why does my rigid body stop moving randomly mid animation

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I have a rigid body that I'm trying to use for a satisfying marble run however it seems that midway through the ball just stops moving and interacting with the animations I put into place.

Comment: can have different reasons and since you didn't show us any settings, you should improve your question. Since i assume you are a beginner, best would be to provide blend file, so we can check it out on our own.

Comment: Maybe go into the Scene panel > Rigid Body World > Cache and check the Simulation End value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change the *End Frame* in the *Timeline* or under *Output Properties* > *Frame Range*, these values are the playback and rendering frame range. By default Blender is set to a frame range of 1 to 250 at startup.

End frame of Playback/Render frame range:

[image: render frame range]

The same frame range is used for the *Simulation Start* and *End* in the *Scene Properties* > *Rigid Body World* > *Cache* settings by default. However, when you change the playback / rendering frame range the animation will last longer, but the simulation cache will not be extended automatically.

The rigid body simulation will stop when the end frame of the cache is reached, not the end of the playback/render frame range. This is for example to avoid simulating much longer than needed, if the simulation only takes place in a part of the animation. You have to adjust it manually.

End frame of Simulation cache:

[image: simulation cache]

Comment: Thank you so much this was the problem exactly it works now thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The above answer hit it right on the head. I just wanted to add that if you have this issue with any cloth physics, you have to adjust the simulation end in Physics Properties>Cache. It should be the same with other physics too.